# Is this question about citations on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, close-reasons

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137075/influence-of-author-on-other-authors) was first closed as off-**topic** and then reopened. The edits did not change the **topic** of the question, they only added and removed details. So if the question was off-topic, by keeping the same topic it remained off-topic.

Is the question on-topic or off-topic?

If you think that the edits changed its **topic**, please explain in what way exactly they changed its **topic**.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider it on-topic but in need of clarification. I definitely find it unclear the meaning of

> influenced how strongly by a certain academic author X?

How do you evaluate the strength of the influence between authors? Could you please expand *in the question* about this?

Comment: Paradoxically, the question has been closed while it was formulated more precisely, and it was reopened while it had the formulation you cite.

Comment: @root I haven't voted on that question, but the first version was definitely clearer and better to me. Take into account that the reopen votes might have started to accumulate before your edits.

Comment: You talk about "need of clarification", whereas the close reason was "off-topic". Also, my current meta question is about "off-topic".

Comment: @root As I said, I'd consider the question in its original form as _on topic_, and I'd disagree with the close voters. However, in its current form is unclear. I'd revert it to the original form.